# Simple Correlated Data Generation

Tags: matlab

I came across the following code where data(:,1) is supposed to generate values correlated with the first set by rho.

```
nDataPts  = 20;    
rho       = .8;    
intercept = .0;

data      = zeros(nDataPts,2);     
data(:,2) = randn (nDataPts,1);   
data(:,1) = randn (nDataPts,1) .* sqrt(1.0-rho^2) + (data (:,2).*rho) + intercept;
```

I was wondering why we need
`.*sqrt(1.0-rho^2)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the the Cholesky decomposition (CholD) of the covariance matrix that defines the correlation that you wish to obtain.

This [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163470/generating-correlated-random-numbers-why-does-cholesky-decomposition-work) is helpful in understanding why the generated random variable Z = LX has the covariance matrix Q, where L is the CholD of Q and X is a matrix of random normal deviates.

For a correlation of 0.8 this would look like this:

```
C = [1.0 0.8; 0.8 1.0]
U = chol(C) % will have value [1.0 0.8; 0 0.6]
```

The algorithm that calculates the decomposition (see Wikipedia section on "Computation" for the Cholesky–Banachiewicz and Cholesky–Crout algorithms; link below) will have the effect of producing the values `rho` and `sqrt(1 - rho^2)` in `U(1,2)` and `U(2,2)`, respectively.

The formula you used is basically the same as multiplying a two-column matrix of normal deviates by the CholD, as follows:

```
C= [ 1.0 0.8; 0.8 1.0 ];
U = chol(C);
data = randn(10, 2) * U;
```

The first column remains unchanged (only 1.0 in column 1 of the CholD) and the second is modified to have the desired covariance matrix.

This can be generalized for more variables as follows:

```
C= [ 1.0 0.8 0.4; 0.4 1.0 0.4; 0.8 0.4 1.0 ];
U = chol(C);
data = randn(10, 3) * U;
```

Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) on CholD mentions this method under "Monte Carlo simulation." Also Matlab [doc page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) on `randn` mentions this method.